# Error from Code::Blocks 17.12 with MinGW installer in it GCC

Tags: boost, codeblocks

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The above is simple code in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) with [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29).

As I am new to Boost and linking to Code::Blocks, I did all compiling, b2, etc. attached lib files, etc. somewhere mistake.

*harmonious* is my project name and cpp file.

I don’t understand the \ stray error and how to correct and get out of this error.

As it shows in *.hpp* files. How can I fix this error?

It gives this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in harmonious (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
:0|2|warning: missing whitespace after the macro name|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|30|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|27|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|49|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\assert.hpp|79|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\assert.hpp|82|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\assert.hpp|83|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\assert.hpp|85|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\range_fwd.hpp|17|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\range_fwd.hpp|20|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\range_fwd.hpp|23|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|37|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|39|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|42|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|67|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\mutable_iterator.hpp|70|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|36|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|36|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|36|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|36|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|36|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|38|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|40|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|65|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\range\const_iterator.hpp|68|error: stray '\' in program|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|280|warning: 'class boost::system::error_category::std_category' has pointer data members [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|280|warning:   but does not override 'boost::system::error_category::std_category(const boost::system::error_category::std_category&)' [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|280|warning:   or 'operator=(const boost::system::error_category::std_category&)' [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(boost::system::error_code)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|27|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(boost::system::error_code, const string&)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|30|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(boost::system::error_code, const char*)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|33|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(int, const boost::system::error_category&)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|36|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(int, const boost::system::error_category&, const string&)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|39|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp||In constructor 'boost::system::system_error::system_error(int, const boost::system::error_category&, const char*)':|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\system\system_error.hpp|43|warning: 'boost::system::system_error::m_what' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|
:0|2|error: expected '>' before ':' token|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|30|note: in expansion of macro 'C'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|36|error: 'T1' does not name a type|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|43|error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 1)|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|34|note: provided for 'template<bool <anonymous> > struct boost::mpl::if_c'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|67|error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 1)|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|34|note: provided for 'template<bool <anonymous> > struct boost::mpl::if_c'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|70|error: 'almost_type_' is not a class or namespace|
:0|2|error: expected nested-name-specifier before ':' token|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\aux_\na_spec.hpp|152|note: in definition of macro 'BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_PARAM'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|27|note: in expansion of macro 'C'|
:0|2|error: expected '>' before ':' token|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\aux_\na_spec.hpp|152|note: in definition of macro 'BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_PARAM'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|27|note: in expansion of macro 'C'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: expected nested-name-specifier|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: expected ';' at end of member declaration|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|error: 'f_' does not name a type|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|38|error: 'f_' has not been declared|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|38|error: redeclaration of 'typedef int boost::mpl::eval_if<<anonymous> >::type'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|37|note: previous declaration 'typedef<typeprefixerror> boost::mpl::eval_if<<anonymous> >::type'|
:0|2|error: expected '>' before ':' token|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|49|note: in expansion of macro 'C'|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: expected nested-name-specifier|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: expected ';' at end of member declaration|
C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp|59|error: 'f_' does not name a type|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 10 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Have a look at this to help you with your editing https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I wonder, I can't find anything in the source - the first suspect is a `\\` used as a line continuation, perhaps in a MACRO used throughout the code, but I cannot see anything in the online source. Could you upload somewhere one of the offending files, and link it in your question?

Comment: One of the offending files in the below link if.hpp  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/mpl/if.hpp      It says error C:\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\if.hpp|30|error: stray '\' in program|